# Echo PHP in html list

Tags: php, html

I recently started learning PHP and I'm trying to echo a PHP value in my `li element`. Ive tried echoing all the HTML code through PHP but the div class doesn't work and neither does the `$username`. When I write the HTML code and just try echoing the PHP, the `$username` still doesn't work.

```
<?php
session_start();
$usrnm = $_SESSION['username'];
$username = 'aaaaaaa';
?>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="usrnmBar.css">   

</head>
<body>
<h1> This is a test </h1>
<div class="usrnmbar"> 
<ul>
<li><a href="post_ad.php">Post Ad</a></li>
<li> <?php echo $username; ?></li>
</ul>
</div><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the file saved with a `.php` extension?

Comment: Is the file actually parsing? Or is it just outputting the PHP as plain text?

Comment: With "doesn't' work", what do you mean? Don't you get output, do you see the PHP source in the browser, or just an empty value... ?

Comment: What is the name of the page?

Comment: Usrnmbar.php. im using XAMPP though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe your session 'username' is empty? And this little "error" crashes your application.

Try this:

```
<?php
session_start();
$username = 'aaaaaaa';
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$usrnm = $_SESSION['username'];
?>
```

BTW -> What is in your error.log?